# IS vs. AS vs. IsAssignableFrom - What are the differences when checking for objectTypes and Interfaces?

Tags: c#, performance, object, interface, operators

I'm sort of new to C# and i was wondering if you could help me out.

**The scenario:**

```
public bool ObjectImplementsSpecificInterface (object obj)
{
    // 1.
    if (obj is IExampleInterface) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    // 2.
    var tmp = obj as IExampleInterface;
    if (tmp != null) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    // 3.
    if (typeof(IExampleInterface).IsAssignableFrom (obj.GetType ())) 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**The Goal:** Determine wether the object o implements the given Interface-Definition `IExampleInterface` or not.

**The questions:**

- Which implementation is best practice?
- Disregarding the first question, which one is technically the most correct?
- What are the specific differences in the operators? *MSDNAA isn't truly detailed on them.*
- Which call takes the longest / shortest?

Comment: Use `is` construction (variant 1) or `as` (variant 2) when you need value further.

Comment: I can't imagine this has not been covered here before.

Comment: I thought so as well, but i could only find answers talking about the specific operators, but not in comparison to each other. if you find a thread that answers my question feel free to link it! :)

Comment: 4: `typeof(IExampleInterface).IsInstanceOfType(obj)`. You should check `obj` for null before calling `obj.GetType()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. var impInterface = obj is ISampleInterface;
2. What do you mean by "technically" ? They all work.  if all you want ois to know whether it implments the interface, that's what `is` is for.  If you want a new variable which is cast as the interface, then use `as`.
3. `is` determines if object derives from a type and returns a Boolean.   `as` attempts to cast the object as the type, and return the new variable cast to the type, or null if it cannot. (but you know this from your question).
4. `as` should probably take longer, even if the cast works.

Comment: Here is the reference for the above comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx I was about to post the same.

Comment: By *technically* i ment from the most c-sharp-ish point of view. So basically which one os the way to go when looking at how c# works.

Comment: I am just as head-scratching about what "c-Sharp-ish" means.  Clearly they are both C#.  Which one is the "way-to-go" depends on what you are trying to do, determine if the variable refers to an object that derives from some specified type, or cast it to that type.  That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 6):

"Is" operator allows you to check if particular instance is of particular type or inherits this type wheras IsAssignableFrom allows you to check if a Type is castable to another Type.

So if you have a situation where you must evaluate if some object is of particular type then you use is:

```
Random r = new Random();
if (r is Random)
{
    reutrn true;
}
```

But if you have only type like such method:

```
public bool CheckIfTypeIsRandom(Type typeKnownAtRuntime)
{
     if (typeof(Random).IsAssignableFrom(typeKnownAtRuntime) 
     {
         return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Then you must use IsAssignableFrom.

Answer (score 5):

All three ways will provide the same result, and take roughly the same time, but only the first one is designed specifically for your situation.

When you start with an object, and all you need is to know whether or not its class implements a given interface, the first approach (i.e. the `is` operator) is the most appropriate.

The second approach is there for cases when you need to find out if an object is an implementation of an interface, *and* also use that object after casting it to the interface. If you plan to throw away the result of the cast after `null`-checking it, there is no point in performing the cast in the first place.

The third approach is mostly for use with reflection, when you have a `System.Type` object instead of the object itself.

Comment: *The third approach is mostly for use with reflection, when you have a System.Type object instead of the object itself.* Even for generics it has some uses...

Answer (score 3):

The gathered information and propably correct answer from the posts below is the following:

**Operator `is`**:

- Should be used to determine wether the object implements an interface or is of a specific type, so this is the answer to my question: *Which one is best practice?*

**Operator `as`**:

- should take longer than `is`.
- is generally used to store the object into a `var` that will represent the correct type.
- used to process the object further aka. call a function or check the type of the interface.

**Operator `isAssignableFrom`**:

- Checks wether the object can be casted to another type.
- Should be used if the type of the object is unknown during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you just want to check, if an object is of a type or implements an interface, use `is`.

2) If you want to check the type or interface and do some stuff with the object, use `as`. So instead of:

```
if (obj is A) {
    A casted = (A) obj;
    casted.MethodOfA ();
}
```

You should do

```
A casted = obj as A
if (casted != null) {
    casted.MethodOfA ();
}
```

3) Use this method only when 1) is not available, e.g. you have the type as an object of type `Type` instead of of `T`.

Comment: Oops, my bad. No, reflection does not play a part in it.